# Django channels working with WS:// but not with WSS://

Tags: django, websocket, django-channels, daphne

I followed explanations from [django-channels tutorial](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial/index.html) and was able to run a chat locally.

However, it does not work in production.

Here is the output from  debugger :

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://www.example.com/ws/chat/lobby/' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404
    (anonymous) @ (index):23
(index):40 Chat socket closed unexpectedly
    chatSocket.onclose @ (index):40
(index):56 WebSocket is already in CLOSING or CLOSED state.
    document.querySelector.onclick @ (index):56
    document.querySelector.onkeyup @ (index):47
```

Here is the javascript I use to try having it work with our https website :

```
const roomName = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('room-name').textContent);
var loc = window.location;
var wsStart = 'ws://';
if (loc.protocol === 'https:') {
    wsStart = 'wss://'
}
const chatSocket = new WebSocket(
    wsStart
    + window.location.host
    + '/ws/chat/'
    + roomName
    + '/'
);
```

I use redisgreen for redis :

```
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer',
        'CONFIG': {
            "hosts": [('redis://:xxxxxxx@great-whale-0077a76ca7.redisgreen.net:11042/')]
        },
    },
}
```

The rest of the code is as per the tutorial.

I am not sure how I should address this issue. Any clue ? Is it required to implement Daphne to run channels in production ? Or did I do something wrong ?

Thanks a lot for your help.